# syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator in bash addition

Tags: bash, cpu-usage

I am getting the error: "line 9: 0.0000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".65")":

Please suggest how to fix this

Tried this:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  IFS=' ' read -r -a pids <<< $(echo $(pgrep nr-softmodem -d ' ') )
  cpu_sum=0.0000;
  mem=0;
  for i in "${pids[@]}";
      do
     cpu=$(top -b -n1 -p "$i" -H | tail -n +8 | awk '{ if ($9 !=0) {sum += $9; count++} } END    {if (count !=0) {avg =sum/count; print avg}}')
 
         cpu_sum=$(echo $((cpu_sum +=cpu ))) 
 done
 echo "$cpu_sum"
```

Expected output:

```
56.65
```

Output seen:

```
./top_gNB1.sh: line 9: 0.0000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0000")
./top_gNB1.sh: line 9: 56.65: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".65")
0
```

Comment: There is no need to do `$(echo $(( ... )))`. It's equivalent to just doing `$(( ... ))`. Also, add a space after the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Bash can only do integer arithmetic, so you get a syntax error when you give it a decimal point.

Instead of:

```
         cpu_sum=$(echo $((cpu_sum +=cpu )))
```

Try:

```
         cpu_sum=$(echo $cpu_sum + $cpu | bc)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives error:
     (standard_in) 2: syntax error

Comment: On which line does it give an error?

Comment: That sounds like `$cpu` is either empty or contains something other than a number. Maybe try something like `xxd <<< "$cpu"` to confirm it doesn't have any tricky characters in it before passing it into `bc`.

Comment: In your Awk script, you have `END    {if (count !=0) {avg =sum/count; print avg}}` - so if `count` is 0, it will not print anything and `cpu` will be set to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, untested, letting awk do the artihmetic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=' ' read -r -a pids <<< $(echo $(pgrep nr-softmodem -d ' ') )
cpu_sum=0
mem=0
for i in "${pids[@]}"; do
    cpu_sum=$(
        top -b -n1 -p "$i" -H |
        tail -n +8 |
        awk -v cpu_sum="$cpu_sum" '
            $9 { sum += $9; count++ }
            END {
                if ( count ) {
                    avg = sum / count
                }
                print avg + cpu_sum
            }
        '
    )
done
echo "$cpu_sum"
```

The line `IFS=' ' read -r -a pids <<< $(echo $(pgrep nr-softmodem -d ' ') )` could be improved but that's a different question.